# Can the below code be Optimized and include the logic to check for related opportunityteammember records before updating checkbox to true?

Tags: trigger, performance, delete

Need help in Optimizing below code.

Requirement is to update "opportunity shared" checkbox on "`Opportunity`"  object whenever opportunity is un-shared. (Delete trigger on "`Opportunityteammember`" object).

```
 trigger SharedOpportunity on OpportunityTeamMember (after delete) {

 List<Id> idOpp = new List<Id>();
 List<Opportunity> OpportunityToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

    if(trigger.isDelete) {

        for (OpportunityTeamMember op : trigger.old) {

           idOpp.add(op.OpportunityId);
        }         
    }

    if(idOpp.isEmpty()) return;

    for(Id id : idOpp) {


        Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(Id = id);
        opportunity.Opportunity_Shared__c  = false;

        OpportunityToUpdate.add(opportunity);

    }

    if(OpportunityToUpdate.size() > 0)
        Database.update(OpportunityToUpdate);   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger will fail any time there is more than one `OpportunityTeamMember` on a record. It'll update the `Opportunity.Opportunity_Shared__c` field to `false` even when there is still an `OpportunityTeamMember` present other than the one deleted.

You'd need to perform a query before you decide which records to update. One approach would run roughly like this:

```
for (OpportunityTeamMember op : Trigger.old) {
   idOpp.add(op.OpportunityId);
}         

for (Opportunity o : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM OpportunityTeamMembers) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :idOpp]) {
    if (o.OpportunityTeamMembers.size() == 0) {
        opportunitiesToUpdate.add(new Opportunity(Id = o.Id, Opportunity_Shared__c = false));
    }
}

update opportunitiesToUpdate;
```

Your code as written is a bit "wordy". It's not terribly inefficient, but you could easily compress it in a way similar to the above and remove the unnecessary `if` checks.